# Add Page With Parent ID

Tags: plugin-development, wp-insert-post

I am writing a plugin that upon activation creates a set of pages.  The first page that I create I want to be the parent of the rest of the pages that are added.  For some reason, this is not working.  Can someone please take a look at my code and tell me what I have wrong?

The code I use to add the first page and return the page ID:

```
$ssm_page = array(
        'post_title'    => 'Parent Page',
                'post_content'  => 'This is the parent page.',
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'post_type'     => 'page',
                'post_author'   => 1,
                'post_category' => array(8,39),
                'page_template' => 'template-fullwidth.php'
    );

    $ssm_page_id = wp_insert_post( $ssm_page, $wp_error );
```

The code I use to add the subsequent pages and adding the 'post_parent' attribute:

```
$login_page = array(
                'post_title'    => 'First Child Page',
                'post_content'  => 'This is the first child page.',
                'post_parent'   => $ssm_page_id,
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'post_type'     => 'page',
                'post_author'   => 1,
                'post_category' => array(8,39),
                'page_template' => 'template-fullwidth.php'
);

wp_insert_post( $login_page );
```

What am I doing wrong?  All of the pages are created but none of the child pages have the parent page set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems as though the page_template property is deprecated according to the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

Comment: ok, you just posted 10 seconds before me ;-)

Comment: yeah, I kept looking until I found something and it looks like I did find the reason and thank you for posting your answer as well.

Comment: I tested your code and it worked without the `page_template` part, with it the `wp_insert_post()` just returned `0`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to skip this part of your post array:

```
'page_template' => 'template-fullwidth.php'
```

since this option is not part of the default options according to the Codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post